# Error while open app after using pyinstaller

Tags: python, mysql-python, pyinstaller

I'm getting error while open my app after using pyinstaller before using pyinstaller when the app still in .py it's working 100%

after that I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\users\deounix\appdata\local\temp
.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\MySQLdb\__init__.py"
  File "c:\users\deounix\appdata\local\temp
.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\_mysql.py", line 7,
  File "c:\users\deounix\appdata\local\temp
.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\_mysql.py", line 3,
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

what I'm doing is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
from time import sleep

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", port=3306, passwd="123456", db="test")

cur = db.cursor() 

cur.execute("SHOW TABLES")

for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row
sleep(10)
```

Comment: is `pkg_resources` a module you created?

Comment: @Avantol13 I don't know what you mean. I'm doing this after make .py file : pyinstaller test1.py

Comment: @Avantol13 no it's not module I created.